# using underscore to compare two object lists and obtain the unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

We have 2 JavaScript object lists.

```
var AList = [{id:1,name:"AA"},{id:2,name:"BB"},{id:3,name:"CC"},{id:4,name:"DD"},{id:5,name:"EE"},{id:6,name:"FF"}]

var BList = [{id:1,name:"AA"},{id:2,name:"BB"},{id:3,name:"CC"},{id:4,name:"DD"}]
```

we need to eliminate the duplicates from both lists and return what is unique for AList. (id 5 and 6)

I've used a generic JavaScript implementation for this, but I like to implement a more sleek solution based on underscore.

```
for(var i=0;i<AList.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<fBList.length;j++){
        if(AList[i] && fBList[j] && (AList[i].id == BList[j].id)){
            delete AList[i];
        }
    }
}
var uniqueList= _.uniq(AList);
```

After A list is done with deleting the duplicates, there are null elements in place where the duplicates were, therefore we needed to use `_uniq` to get a unique set of values.

```
_.difference(AList,BList)
```

Doesn't provide the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `_.difference` does use strict equality, and there is no way to change that by a custom equality callback. You still need to compute it manually:

```
AList = _.uniq(AList, _.property('id'));
BList = _.uniq(BList, _.property('id'));

var bIds = _.pluck(BList, "id");
_.filter(AList, function(el) { return !_.contains(bIds, el.id); })
```

Comment: did a performance test on both implementations. underscore is clearly slower in terms of performance.


http://jsperf.com/underscorevsjsforloop

Comment: @Sanath: Your test does nothing but *declare* a function. Also, your function does modify `AList` which it must not; and I've also replaced the `delete` with a more appropriate `splice`: http://jsperf.com/underscorevsjsforloop/4

Answer (score 3):

You could combine the two arrays, then get the unique result.

```
var uniqueList = _.uniq(AList.concat(BList), function(item) {
  return item.id;
});
```

Or you could use `_.property(key)`:

```
var uniqueList = _.uniq(AList.concat(BList), _.property('id'));
```

Comment: How about: `_.uniq(AList.concat(BList), _.property('id'))`

Comment: Uh, doesn't the OP want to compute the `difference`?

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble on this as I did, lodash now has a function called `differenceWith` which takes a comparator.

```
_.differenceWith(array, [values], [comparator])
```

https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith

Comment: Along with the link to documentation, it would be good if you show up sample code